# Windows doesn't recognize recovery partition

Tags: boot, recovery-partition

I delete all my partition in my SSD and I install a new operating system.
Before that I copy all files of recovery partition to external disk also hidden files.

I thought that if I set an external disk as bootable, it will work like recovery partition, but it did not work.

Now I create new partition named "Recovery" and placed it all recovery files.
How can I make the new partition like the old? Like this:

[image]

Comment: I don't know what you did has ever worked for anyone but you can try marking your recovery partition active and try access it. [Refer to this for instructions](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/71432-partition-mark-active.html)

Comment: yes I mark active and I set this commad "bootsect /nt60"

Comment: Older Recovery partitions used a custom Master Boot Record to make them work properly, sometimes marking the partition as Active will cause it to load on restart but is near impossible to make it work like the original unless you have a copy of the manufacturers MBR and apply it. Newer PCs have a custom uefi partition that make it work.

Comment: My computer work with uefi and mbr . I have sony vaio z serie